# AWS EMR with SSH, connection to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

In my current configuration, I access first a AWS RedHat via putty (ssh)
then, from this RedHat, I can access via ssh to my EMR.

I am trying to mount S3 on this EMR.
But, I am facing many issues.

- First, I uninstalled fuse
- then I installed required Packages
- then Download and Compile Latest Fuse
- then Download and Compile Latest S3FS
- everything seems OK until there.

Then, I have some doubts on the part where I should setup the "Access Key"
I am not sure if what I retrieved I good :-/ and I don't know how to check it.
So could you please give me explainations on how to get it ?

Then, I try to mount S3
But I got always this error: /mnt/s3: Transport endpoint is not connected

I can mount S3 from the RedHat where I am connected with my own user. 
On ERM, I am connected with "hadoop" user.

I don't really know where to look at to do that, could you please provide me some guiding ?

Comment: Why do you want to "mount" Amazon S3? This is not a recommended technique. Are you trying to access data from S3 from your Amazon EMR cluster? EMR has in-built connectivity to S3. What is your use-case?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein If you say so, there is probably something I misunderstood... But I don't know how to connect to my S3 file while Im in SSH connection. I know how to access S3 via HUE, but not via SSH... If you could explain a little bit how I can do that, that could be really great.

Comment: Is this an EMR-specific use-case, or simply the need to access content from Amazon S3 while an on Amazon EC2 instance? Have you looked at the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)? http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: The semantics of the S3 file system are not that of a Posix file system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3